# Why React component doesn't re-render (change styles) when props changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I made a `TagItem` JSXElement that color changes when a user clicks/touches.

It receives a prop `isSelected` and it also has its own state `selected` inside, which initial value is prop `isSelected`.
Its style changes depending on `selected` state but the style doesn't change when prop `isSelected` value changes...

The reason I figured out is that its state doesn't change even when prop `isSelected` changes.

I don't know why this happens. Does anyone know?

The code is like this.

```js
type TagItemProps = {
      tag: Tag;
      isSelected: boolean;
      onSelect: (tag: Tag) => boolean;
      onDeselect: (tag: Tag) => void;
    };
    
const TagItem = ({ tag, isSelected = false, onSelect, onDeselect }: TagItemProps) => {
      const [selected, setSelected] = useState(isSelected);

      console.log("isSelected: ", isSelected);
      console.log("selected: ", selected);
    
      const handleSelect = useCallback(() => {
        if (!onSelect(tag)) return;
        setSelected(true);
      }, [onSelect, tag]);
    
      const handleDeselect = useCallback(() => {
        onDeselect(tag);
        setSelected(false);
      }, [onDeselect, tag]);
    
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[styles.container, selected ? styles.selected : null]}
          onPress={selected ? handleDeselect : handleSelect}
        >
          <Text style={[styles.text, selected ? { color: '#fff' } : null]}>
            {capitalizeFirstLetter(tag.name)}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
};
    
export default TagItem;
    
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 12,
        margin: 5,
      },
      selected: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
      },
      text: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
});
```

As you can see from above, when state `selected` is true, `styles.selected` should be applied.

I confirm that prop `isSelected` changes but not `selected` state, by logging in console.

```js
console.log("isSelected: ", isSelected); // false
console.log("selected: ", selected);
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic case of copying props into local state -- which you usually do not want to do as it introduces a surface area for bugs, including the one you are seeing. If something is available as a prop -- what is the purpose of copying it into local state? You should instead use callbacks to alter wherever the state of that prop lives in the ancestors. Copying means you now have to manage keeping the local state and prop in sync -- which is why usually copying in the first place is an antipattern.

The reason the state doesn't update when `isSelected` changes is because the parameter to `useState` is only its *initial value*. By design, even when a rerender occurs due to the prop changing, the state item wont update. Copying it into local state means its up to you to keep them in sync (common cause of bugs).

Two choices:

**Option A**

Don't copy props into state, so you don't even need to deal with making sure the props and internal state are in sync. Use `isSelected` directly and remove the state item. To set the selected state, you will need to pass down into the component from the parent a callback over props -- which accepts the changed value and changes the state in that parent component. This gets rid of the pointless barrier in between the props and the actual thing you are rendering.

**Option B**

If you must keep a copy of the state around for some reason, make sure you update the state when the props change with an additional effect.

```
type TagItemProps = {
      tag: Tag;
      isSelected: boolean;
      onSelect: (tag: Tag) => boolean;
      onDeselect: (tag: Tag) => void;
    };
    
const TagItem = ({ tag, isSelected = false, onSelect, onDeselect }: TagItemProps) => {
      const [selected, setSelected] = useState(isSelected);

      useEffect(() => {
          setSelected(isSelected )
     }, [isSelected ])

      console.log("isSelected: ", isSelected);
      console.log("selected: ", selected);
    
      const handleSelect = useCallback(() => {
        if (!onSelect(tag)) return;
        setSelected(true);
      }, [onSelect, tag]);
    
      const handleDeselect = useCallback(() => {
        onDeselect(tag);
        setSelected(false);
      }, [onDeselect, tag]);
    
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[styles.container, selected ? styles.selected : null]}
          onPress={selected ? handleDeselect : handleSelect}
        >
          <Text style={[styles.text, selected ? { color: '#fff' } : null]}>
            {capitalizeFirstLetter(tag.name)}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
};
    
export default TagItem;
    
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 12,
        margin: 5,
      },
      selected: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
      },
      text: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didnt know copying props to state is antipattern!! And your explanation helped me know about React a lot more! I took your option A as I realised I was doing kind of duplicated process about `isSelected` value. The `TagItem` was used in parent `TagList` component and isSelected is already calculated there and passed into `TagItem` so no need to handle the state inside itself.

Comment: Cool yep, you got it!

Answer (score 2):

Just leaving the code I ended up with (@Adam 's option A) and it works totally fine.

```
type TagItemProps = {
  tag: Tag;
  isSelected: boolean;
  onSelect?: (tag: Tag) => boolean;
  onDeselect?: (tag: Tag) => void;
};

const TagItem = ({ tag, isSelected, onSelect, onDeselect }: TagItemProps) => {
  const handleSelect = useCallback(() => {
    onSelect && onSelect(tag);
  }, [onSelect, tag]);

  const handleDeselect = useCallback(() => {
    onDeselect && onDeselect(tag);
  }, [onDeselect, tag]);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={[styles.container, isSelected ? styles.selected : null]}
      onPress={isSelected ? handleDeselect : handleSelect}
    >
      <Text style={[styles.text, isSelected ? { color: '#fff' } : null]}>
        {capitalizeFirstLetter(tag.name)}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```